# Не работает плагин Autoprefixer для Sublime Text 3

Tags: node.js, sublime-text-3, autoprefixer

Для Sublime Text 3 установил плагин Autoprefixer, но при запуске плагина для добавления CSS-префиксов выскакивает окно с ошибками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем тут проблема?